# Is it possible to send virtual key code from Windows Runtime Component authored in C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++-winrt

I am developing a Windows Runtime Component which handles on-SoC GPIO buttons by using  `Windows.Devices.Gpio`.
While the button is pressed, I need to send relative virtual key code.
However, the `SendInput()` function is not available for a Windows Runtime Component.
Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The restriction of `SendInput` applies to the application model, not the delivery mechanism. You cannot use `SendInput` when targeting the UWP. That doesn't necessarily mean, that you cannot use it in a Windows Runtime component. I don't know of the technical details, but I guess it should be possible to write a Windows Runtime Component for programs targeting the classic desktop application model.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you so much. In fact, the Windows Runtime Component can be used by legacy Win32 application after Windows 10 19H1. For my question, I have moved the `SendInput()' function to the other Win32 application and execute `SendInput()` according to the registered `ValueChanged` event. Finally, it works! However, I still want to know if there is an alternative method in the Windows Runtime component that can perform the same method.

Comment: Could you please tell me what your OS is? Is your app running on Windows IoT Core/Enterprise or normal windows? In addition, I'm a little confused about "send relative virtual key code", can you show more details about this?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The OS is Windows 10 Professional 1903. The device has several function buttons which are not supported by Windows. Therefore, I need to handle the buttons pressed/released through `GpioPin.ValueChanged` event. While an event is received by the library, I need to send virtual key code and scan code according to the pressed button.

Comment: Do you mean you want to simulate keyboard input programattically when you press button? Maybe you could try to use [Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection?view=winrt-19041) to achieve it.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Yes, you are correct. I will try Injection! Thank you very much~